# Custom filter method react-table, two different match types on same column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have a table that contains list of tld's which can be filtered via a search box or buttons for specific categories. The buttons filter based on a list of tld's while the search box should fuzzy match the tld's.

```
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'TLD',
        accessor: 'tld',
        filter: multiFilter,
        Cell: (props) => {
          const onSale = props.row.original.sale
          return (
            <div>
              .{props.value} {onSale ? <span className="font-bold text-purple m-left-1">Sale</span> : null}
            </div>
          )
        },
      },
```

Button filtering

```
  <button autoFocus className="py-1 px-4 text-sm focus:bg-blue focus:rounded-full" onClick={() => setFilter('tld', undefined)}>All</button>
  <button className="py-1 px-4 text-sm focus:bg-blue focus:rounded-full" onClick={() => setFilter('tld', sale)}>Sale</button>
```

Search box filtering

```
 <input id="tld-search-box" value={searchFilterInput} onChange={handleSearchFilterChange} placeholder={'Enter a domain extension here'} className="border border-gray-300 p-2 w-[640px] rounded-full" />
```

For the buttons I had to make a custom filter method

```
  function multiFilter(rows, columnIds, filterValue) {
    return filterValue.length === 0
      ? rows
      : rows.filter((row) =>
        filterValue.includes(String(row.original[columnIds])),
      );
  }
```

And this is the search filter method which ends up using setFilter so it flows through the custom filter method eventually also

```
  const handleSearchFilterChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value || undefined
    const trimmedValue = value ? value.replace(/^\./g, '') : undefined
    setFilter('tld', trimmedValue)
    setSearchFilterInput(value)
  }
```

The problem I have is since they both use the custom filter method in the end, the search box filtering is an exact match per the includes method `filterValue.includes(String(row.original[columnIds])),`. I want the search box to match anything that contains the value entered however and I am not sure how to do this since they both act on the column. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I used `filter: 'includesValue'` in columns with react-table v7 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose global filtering could also solve this issue but I ended up finding that the two search types were of different JS types. The buttons were type object while the search bar was string so this solved the issue:

```
  function multiFilter(rows, columnIds, filterValue) {
    return filterValue.length === 0 ? rows : rows.filter((row) => {
      let match = String(row.original[columnIds])
      return typeof filterValue === 'object'
        ? filterValue.includes(match) // Check to see if match is in array
        : match.includes(filterValue) // do sub string match for strings
      })
  }
```